# Why doesnt my subcribed variable update when observable is updated?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, rxjs5

I am using angular 5.2.9 and angularfire to access my firestore database. When I call a function on load.service.ts it runs the following function  block with a argument of status and returns an observable; this gets assigned to an observable in the calling component. This works perfectly if you navigate to the component for the first time since the default status is "Active". If you set the status to "Complete" I don't get any results.

*****************Component.ts ****************

```
//this is inside the constructor
private loads = new BehaviorSubject<Load[]>(new Array<Load>());
public currentLoads = this.loads.asObservable();

this.userService.currentUser.subscribe(user => {
  this.user = user;
  //loadsService depends on user
  this.loadsObservable = this.loadService.getLoads("Active");
  this.loadsObservable.subscribe(loads => {
    this.loads = loads;
  });
});


//this gets fired by a button group  
onChangeFilter(event: any){
  this.loadsObservable = this.loadService.getLoads(this.currentStatus);
}
```

*************** load.service.ts *****************

```
getLoads(status: string){
  const loadCollection = this.afs.collection<Load>('loads');
  loadCollection.ref.where("status", "==", status).where("driver/id","==", this.user.id)
  return loadCollection.valueChanges();
});
```

Comment: forgot to mention that this.currentStatus is bound to the toggle button group and does sent the parameter correctly to getLoads

Comment: What type exactly is returned by `getLoads`?

Comment: the following is being returned from angularfire `Observable<Observable<Load>> `

Comment: I had to map it and return. But now it works. Thank you! :D

Comment: No problem. Aha, from your example it looked like it returns Observable<Observable<Load[]>>. So when you say you *map it*, are you using `toArray`, `scan` or `reduce` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because in `onChangeFilter` you exchanged the references in `this.loadsObservable`, but you've subscribed only to the first one in the constructor. The second isn't subscribed to, so the emitted items never appear in your view.

I assume you are using `currentLoads` in your template with `async` pipe. In that case you can directly in `onChangeFilter` have eg. this code:

```
onChangeFilter(event: any) {
  this.currentLoads = this.loadService.getLoads(this.currentStatus)
                                      .switch();
}
```

That way you get the inner Observable (the loads themselves) from the outer Observable you get out of `getLoads` call. Each time the outer emits, the subscription to the previous inner Observable is dropped thanks to the `switch` operator, more on that [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switch). With this approach, you don't need to subscribe manually or have auxiliary varibles like your `private loads`.

Comment: So now I get: `The 'this' context of type 'Observable<Load[]>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<Observable<Load>>`